# How to fix missing SRS in geotiff using geotrellis

Tags: gis, gdal, geotiff, geotrellis

I have a bunch of geotiffs without SRS.
It is possible to fix the SRS using GDAL command:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:25832 srcfile targetfile
```

How can I replace the GDAL command using geotrellis code ?

Answer (score 4):

```
import geotrellis.proj4._
import geotrellis.raster.io.geotiff._

val fileName: String = ???
val tif = SinglebandGeoTiff(fileName)
val targetCrs = CRS.fromName("EPSG:25832”)
val reprojected = tif.projectedRaster.reproject(targetCrs)
GeoTiff(reprojected.raster,  reprojected.crs).write("/Users/eugene/reprojected.tif")
```

You can use `MultibandGeoTiff` if you're working with multiple bands.

Comment: @ViliamSimko take a look into https://github.com/geotrellis/geotrellis/pull/1697 (i double checked that tiifs without crs would be loaded as tiffs with LatLng), however you can specify neccesary crs during the ingest process, can you check this new feature? If no, any problem tile example would be great!

Comment: @ViliamSimko looks like yes, it _reprojects_, not assignes crs;